# два dhcp в одной сети для pxe

Tags: linux, dhcp, pxe

Добрый день.
Ситуация следующая. Есть роутер на нем dhcp сервер. Есть PXE сервер. Задача: Сделать так чтобы PXE сервер получал адрес автоматически. После чего мог раздавать PXE клиентам адреса и путь к файлу загрузки(TFTP на нем же). Можно даже и без автоматического получения адреса PXE сервером.

Может кто что подсказать. Задача решаемая, но настолько давно что уже и не упомню как

Comment: на первом сервере dhcp единственного клиента (второго dhcp) прописать по mac адресу. других как-то игнорировать или они автоматом будут игнорироваться. в общем развести их по mac-адресам клиентов

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Смысл двух dhcp в том, что первый раздает адреса всем(Кроме pxe - клиентов) и всегда. Второй все в одном Tftp сервер и dhcp сервер, и реагировать он должен только в том случае когда ip адрес просит pxe клиент что бы выдать ему (клиенту) еще и путь до файла загрузки. Как это выглядит в живую. Нам нужно загрузится по сети(memtest например). Включаем сервер(Который стоит на ноутбуке). Выбираем на клиенте загрузку по сети, грузимся. Почему не таскать  просто флешку? У меня их гроздь, надоело таскать. ищу альтернативу.

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с такого вопроса:

## Можно ли сажать более одного DHCP на один широковещательный сегмент?

Да, но с оговоркой - диапазоны раздачи у серверов не должны пересекаться.

## Зачем это делать?

Для резервирования - если один из DHCP упал, второй, третий и т. д. поработают за него.

## Как это будет работать?

DHCP работает по принципу общежития - кто первый встал, того и тапки, чашка, санузел, котэ - кто первый ответил, у того адрес и возьмут. Чтобы это происходило более определенным образом, надо настраивать оба сервера.

## Нужно ли автору делать то, что он собрался делать?

Маловероятно. Автор хочет сделать странное, разделив роли серверов не горизонтально (Серверы DHCP | Серверы TFTP | Серверы удаленных ФС), а сделав DHCP со неясной ролью (раздавать адреса всем, но не раздавать PXEхнутым?) и пристроив к нему сбоку PXE с отдельной ролью (раздавать адреса на загрузку?). Цели не ясны, задачи не ясны, перспектив стабильной работы не видно.

## Что делать?

Если требуется обеспечить отказоустойчивость:

Сделать N серверов DHCP+TFTP, разрезав пространство адресов между ними. Каждый сервер в качестве TFTP бдует отдавать себя.

Плюсы - вылет любого сервера не скажется на работоспособности загрузки
Минусы - потребуется некоторое время на шлифовку конфигурации.

Comment: **Да, но с оговоркой - диапазоны раздачи у серверов не должны пересекаться.** - неверно.  В описании протокола DHCP сказано, что когда клиент формирует ответ на предложенный адрес - сообщение **DHCPREQUEST**, он задаёт "Конечный адрес по-прежнему широковещательный, поскольку на запрос могли ответить НЕСКОЛЬКО серверов DHCP и в данный момент они могут ожидать ответа на сделанное клиенту предложение. Это сообщает остальным серверам DHCP, что они могут больше не удерживать свои адреса и вернуть их в имеющиеся пулы."


Короче -  каким сервером воспользуется клиент - он должен решать сам.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Смысл двух dhcp в том, что первый раздает адреса всем(Кроме pxe - клиентов) и всегда. Второй все в одном Tftp сервер и dhcp сервер, и реагировать он должен только в том случае когда ip адрес просит pxe клиент что бы выдать ему (клиенту) еще и путь до файла загрузки. Как это выглядит в живую.

Comment: @seregasemenov, а не проще компьютеры развести по разным vlan?

Answer (score -1):

В настройках клиента DHCP (на рабочих станциях) необходимо задать список предпочтения DHCP серверов. Что бы клиент предпочитал работать с РХЕ, а уж если он не ответил на DHCPDISCOVER, то тогда брать параметры от роутера.

Как это сделать - зависит от клиента. Если клиента пишите Вы сами, то проблем нет.

Comment: Эммм... а как в сетевуху прописать список dhcp-серверов?